# openlayer - javascript zoom in map library/documentation to group data

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am working on a network visualization project. I would like to add a zoom-in like feature of openlayer, wherein, if I zoom-in (or trigger a event), I should be able to view specific nodes of a group when i zoom-in.

is there a library or any documentation that describes this zoomin feature?

Thanks,
Amit